# Python dictionary comparasion

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I got a dict into a dict, looks like this: Key of first outter dict is object, key of inner dicts are parameters of objects. One object is reference and I need to compare values of all parameters of all objects to that one reference object and if there is difference print it, if there is no diff, do nothing. Dict looks like this:

```
{'object-1301': {'act1': 'false',
  'act1x': 'true',
  'act': 'false',
  'actAdv': 'false',
  'actAe': 'false',
  'actArp': 'false',},
 'object-218': {'act1': 'true',
  'act1x': 'false',
  'act': 'false',
  'actAdv': 'false',
  'actAe': 'true',
  'actArt': 'false',}, 
...
 }
```

Code I've so far is, where ref is reference object, dict is dict I copied above:

```
main_dif = {}
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    dif_k = {}
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        try: 
            a = ref[k]
        except:
             a = None
        if a != v:
                dif_k.update({k:v})
    main_dif.update({key:dif_k})
```

The problem I have is next: when reference object doesn't have at all some parameters, but some other objects have, this works well, but when reference object have and other objects don't, there is nothing happen, can't find it.

Comment: Maybe you can first update your question a bit. You are missing an accent in the first row of your example. Also you can replace the `try`/`except` construction by `ref.get(k,None)`. Finally, the grammar needs a bit of attention.

Comment: @Tom de Geus
I have edited my question. I don't miss any row, why you think that?

Comment: What are you trying to do and the desired result?

Comment: in you dictionnary there is something missing for `act1` --> `'act1':`

Comment: As I said, compare values of parameters for all objects with the reference object. If there is a difference, print it (later in excel file). The first row (below header) would be the value of reference object, and below that would be all other objects and their values (which are different from reference). 
Maybe I can send you a screenshot of excel example in pm? @manvi77

Comment: Yes, thank you, I made that mistake manually, in original dict everything is ok.  @Astrom

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more detailed answer. See if this works for you to check keys and values.

```
from pprint import pprint

# Use your own ref, I've just this one all to true for testing.
ref = {
    'act1': 'true',
    'act1x': 'true',
    'act': 'true',
    'actAdv': 'true',
    'actAe': 'true',
    'actArp': 'true',
    }

data = {
    'object-1301': {
        'act1': 'false',
        'act1x': 'true',
        'act': 'false',
        'actAdv': 'false',
        'actAe': 'false',
        'actArp': 'false',
    },
    'object-218': {
        'act1': 'true',
        'act1x': 'false',
        'act': 'false',
        'actAdv': 'false',
        'actAe': 'true',
        'actArt': 'false',
    },
    'object-short': {
        'act1': 'false'
        },
    'object-extra-keys': {
        'act1': 'true',
        'act1x': 'true',
        'act': 'true',
        'actAdv': 'true',
        'actAe': 'true',
        'actArp': 'true',
        'extra': 'true',
    },
    'object-as-ref': {
        'act1': 'true',
        'act1x': 'true',
        'act': 'true',
        'actAdv': 'true',
        'actAe': 'true',
        'actArp': 'true',
        },
    'object-opposite-to-ref': {
        'act1': 'false',
        'act1x': 'false',
        'act': 'false',
        'actAdv': 'false',
        'actAe': 'false',
        'actArp': 'false',
    }
 }

mainDiff = {}

for obj, objDict in data.iteritems():
    currentDict = {}

    # Check if the keys match. 
    if objDict.keys() != ref.keys():
        for key in ref:
            if key not in objDict.keys():
              # Store keys missing from object.
              currentDict[key] = None

        for key in objDict:
            if key not in ref.keys():
                # Store unexpected values in object.
                currentDict[key] = None  

    # Check if values are the same.
    for k, v in objDict.iteritems():
        # Check if the key is in ref to avoid error
        if k in ref:
            # Then compare if values are equal
            if ref[k] != objDict[k]:
                # Then store actual value
                currentDict[k] = v
    # Store differences for current object against object title.
    mainDiff[obj] = currentDict

print 'Differences:'
pprint(mainDiff)
```

Comment: you could replace `None` with "missing" or "extra" if you prefer something more descriptive on printing.

Comment: The problem is that I have about 3000 objects with 300-400 parameters, I copied just a small piece.
Just a moment please

Comment: Oh, this kinda work but I need just a few minutes to check for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I see how you can check against the reference object but the reference object might have other keys.

So I would add a test to check the keys are identical. I am printing here but you could log it to a dictionary or list of errors.

```
main_dif = {}
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    dif_k = {}

    if value.keys() != ref.keys():
        print('Key mismatch for {0}'.format(key))
        print('Ref: {0}.  Actual: {1}'.format(ref.keys(), value.keys()) 

    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        try: 
            a = ref[k]
        except:
             a = None
        if a != v:
                dif_k.update({k:v})
    main_dif.update({key:dif_k})
```

If you convert two list into sets and then subtract them, then you can better calculate extra or missing keys.

Comment: Reference object can have other keys(parameters). That's the point. If have some key that other objects don't, print it and add to other objects value: 'None'.That work in a reverse situation, if other objects have some key what reference don't have it print values of that parameters and add value: 'None to ref obj. Of course, if both objects have same key, I need compare their values. @MichaelAshleyCurrin

Comment: I got this: 
for k, v in value.iteritems():
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I have no idea why

Comment: Please see my newest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
In [17]: refdict
Out[17]: 
{'object-1301': {'act': 'false',
  'act1': 'false',
  'act1x': 'true',
  'actAdv': 'false',
  'actAe': 'false',
  'actArp': 'false'}}

In [18]: mydict
Out[18]: 
{'object-218': {'act': 'false',
  'act1': 'true',
  'act1x': 'false',
  'actAdv': 'false',
  'actAe': 'true',
  'actArt': 'false'}}

for k, v in refdict.iteritems():
    for k1, v1 in mydict.iteritems():
        if k != k1:
            print('Checking for object: {0}'.format(k1))
            for k2, v2 in v.iteritems():
                if k2 in v1:
                    if v[k2] == v1[k2]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print "Differences"
                        print('For Key {0}, Value {1} are different'.format(k2, v1[k2]))
                else:
                    print "Missing key in current object"
                    print k2
            for k3 in v1:
                if k3 not in v:
                    print "Missing key in reference object"
                    print k3

#result
Checking for object: object-218
Differences
For Key act1, Value true are different
Differences
For Key actAe, Value true are different
Missing key in current object
actArp
Differences
For Key act1x, Value false are different
Missing key in reference object
actArt
```